# Icons for custom file types (iOS or OS X)

Tags: ios, icons, document, file-type

I'm looking for information/documentation on creating a custom icon for a document type in my iOS app. I am sure I have seen some Apple developer guide with information about this, but I have been searching and cannot find it!

In the app's Info.plist I have specified a custom document type, and a corresponding exported UTI (conforming to com.apple.package). Xcode makes it quite easy to specify images for these under the "Info" tab of the target settings, but I can't find the information regarding what sizes they should be, or in what situations the document icon will be visible. I believe that iOS automatically creates a 'default' document icon for you using the app icon (as per [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW15) of the HIG), so if I made it possible for users to share the document via email, another user with the app installed on their iOS device would see this default document icon.

Where else might this document icon be seen? Currently in iTunes file sharing the document appears as a directory with the custom file extension - presumably this would change if an icon was specified for the document? When viewing one of the documents in the OS X file system, it appears as a standard white document (i.e. looks like an unknown file type) - is there any way for this to appear with the proper icon, or would the user need a Mac app installed that specifies such a file type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You already found the HIG documentation.  I'm not certain if document icons show up in iTunes, but I doubt it.  I've never seen this from any other app.

From the [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW9) (search for "Document Icons"):

**Document Icons**

> In iOS, the `CFBundleTypeIconFiles` key contains an array of strings with the names of the image files to use for the document icon. Table 3 lists the icon sizes you can include for each device type. You can name the image files however you want but the file names in your `Info.plist` file must match the image resource filenames exactly. (For iPhone and iPod touch, the usable area of your icon is actually much smaller.) For more information on how to create these icons, see *iOS Human Interface Guidelines*.

**Table 3** Document icon sizes for iOS

```
+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
|        Device         |              Sizes               |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| iPad                  | 64 x 64 pixels                   |
|                       | 320 x 320 pixels                 |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| iPhone and iPod touch | 22 x 29 pixels                   |
|                       | 44 x 58 pixels (high resolution) |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The table of sizes is just what I need. I still feel like I've seen another piece of documentation that describes clear zones and such for document icon creation - it could have been for OS X documents though. As far as document icons showing up in iTunes, I have seen it with a few apps (Pages/Numbers/FileMaker Go) but these are all apps that I also have on my Mac. I haven't got an iOS-only app that saves a custom file type to iTunes, but I suspect you might be right. Shame my file packages show as directories, rather than files.

Comment: Here's a link for the same document [for OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101685).

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @TomSwift for your answer help me a lot. I just add this if you have Xcode 6.3.2.

You can not add icon files drag and drop or press "+" button inside info section, instead you must add the icon files names directly info.plist [image]

You must add the fours icons as image above.

Then you can see the icon inside Document Types.

[image]

Comment: I found in Xcode9-beta that if you drag the png image files into your project (not resources file - I put them in a seperate group) then dragged them from the file list on the left on top of the image icon, and then ran the app (for some reason it needed this) it worked and the icons appeared in the plist. But the + button didn't work. Weird hey!

Comment: XCode 11 required that I use the + button to add my images otherwise it didn't recognize them once built and deployed to a device.  Dragging an image into the box seemed like it worked, but something was missing.